# Unable to start activity:UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I want to write a `ListView` in basic format but I get an error:

```
UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

and:

```
androidview.LayoutInfalater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java: some numbers....like 720,658...so on)
```

I know something should be done here in the adapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RelativeLayout rv = new RelativeLayout(c);

    TextView tv = new TextView(c);
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(c);
    ImageView imgv = new ImageView(c);

    tv.setText(s[position]);
    tv1.setText(i[position]);
    imgv.setImageResource(d[position]);

    rv.addView(tv);
    rv.addView(tv1);
    rv.addView(imgv);
    return rv;

}
```

What should I do to solve the problems

The LOGCAT:

```
02-20 16:40:24.967: E/Trace(1715): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-20 16:40:25.819: W/ResourceType(1715): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x000020d0
02-20 16:40:25.819: D/AndroidRuntime(1715): Shutting down VM
02-20 16:40:25.819: W/dalvikvm(1715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x20d0
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3620)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.example.systemzap2.adapt.getView(adapt.java:59)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-20 16:40:25.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Seems like you're not showing us the important part of your code. addView on AdapterView is not supported, because AdapterView is kind of abstract base for ListView, Gallery and so on. See: [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AdapterView.java). Maybe you should just use a ListView?

Comment: can you post your full code for this adapter class?

Comment: post your full logcat

Comment: which one the java or the adapter class code or the 2 layout's code???

Answer (score 128, accepted):

> what should i do???

Correct your code.

> UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not
>   supported in AdapterView

A subclass of `AdapterView` like a `ListView` **can't** have children manually added either in the layout file or added in code. So if you have this in one of your layouts:

```
<ListView // .. other attributes>
     <// other views <-- notice the children of the ListView tag
</ListView>
```

**don't do it**, as this will call the `addView` method of `ListView`, throwing the exception. Instead use:

```
<ListView // .. other attributes />
< // other views
```

You also **can't** use any of the `addView` methods of `ListView` in code like this:

```
listViewReference.addView(anotherView); // <-- don't do it
```

Also, if you use the `LayoutInflater.inflate` method in the code of the `Activity` or the adapter(its `getView` method), **don't pass** the `ListView` as the second parameter. For example, **don't use**:

```
convertView  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_rows, parent);
```

as in Tamilarasi Sivaraj's answer as that will throw the exception again. Instead use:

```
convertView  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_rows, parent, false);
```

Related to the exception you posted in the question, it appears you use the `setText` method with an `int`(one of the `s` or `i` arrays being an `int` array). The problem is that in this case `TextView` will think you're trying to set the text using a string resource like this `R.string.astring`. The `int` you pass is not a string resource so an exception will be thrown. If `s` or `i` is an `int` and you're trying to show it in the `TextView` use this instead:

```
tv.setText(String.valueOf(s[position])); // assuming s is the int array
```

Comment: +1 for the "Also, if you use the LayoutInflater.inflate method in the code of the Activity or the adapter(its getView method), don't pass the ListView as the second parameter"

Comment: Looks like this applies to GridView as well. :(

Comment: The part that was not directly answering the question, solved my problem! (inflation)

Comment: So what's the correct way to do this if addView() doesn't work in code?

Comment: Thank you for the: `convertView  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_rows, parent, false);`

Answer (score 7):

Replace your layout in inflater

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) LayoutInflater
                .from(contex);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);

    }

    txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtName.setText(""+ContactsArr.get(position).get("ContName"));
    txtPhoneNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtContact);
    txtPhoneNumber.setText(""+ContactsArr.get(position).get("ContPhone"));

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me and totally skipped over the answer I needed in @Luksprog's answer because it's buried in it, try using adding the third parameter to the `inflate` method, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832497/avoid-passing-null-as-the-view-root-need-to-resolve-layout-parameters-on-the-in):

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, parent, false);
```

Don't use `true` instead of `false` or you will get the same error that brought you here, because it's trying to attach/add it to the parent, hence the `addView is not supported in AdapterView` error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Like this:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textView; 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try{
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null)  {
                holder = new ViewHolder(); 
                LayoutInflater inflater = context1.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null,true);  

                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgview);

                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtview);

                convertView.setTag(holder);  
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
            }

            holder.textView.setText("your text");
            holder.imageView.setImageResource("your image resource");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);    
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tamilarasi Sivaraj, should i put my tex t view and img view in the place of the child view???

Comment: yes you put your textview and image view in the child view and mention the layout name in LayoutInflater...if you have any queries ask me

Comment: i have edited my code for put textview and imageview from layout to listview using adapter use it...

Answer (score 0):

I also received the issue :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: addView(View,
> LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView Caused by:
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams)
> is not supported in AdapterView

I have forgotten to add **"false"** when I inflate the `.xml`. After adding that it works. My code phrase is as below. I used a `LinearLayout` for my `.xml`.

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_format,parent,false);
    }
```