# addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView - LinearLayout nested inside ListView

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

What Iam trying to do is to have a list of contacts a user can choose from to start a conversation. That contact would have contactee's profile image and username, and would be clickable (opens MessageActivity)

Can someone help me make since of this?

It's telling me:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

Line 18 is:

```
<include
        layout="@layout/mylist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

which is nested inside a ListView. mylist.xml is a linearlayout.

ContactsActivity

```
usersRef.child(friendKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot friendSnapshot) {
                        ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
                        //String friendName = friendSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                        String friendPicture = friendSnapshot.child("image_url").getValue(String.class);
                        ImageView friend_icon = findViewById(R.id.friend_icon2);
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: friendSnapshot.child("username").getChildren()) {
                            ids.add(childSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                            Picasso.get().load(friendPicture).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image).resize(96, 96)
                                    .centerCrop().into(friend_icon);
                            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylist, R.id.Itemname, ids);
                            lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
                            lstView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                            individual_contact.setClickable(true);
                            individual_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MessageActivity.class);
                                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(v.getContext(), intent );
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        throw databaseError.toException();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: There's no JavaScript anywhere in this question.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978296/unable-to-start-activityunsupportedoperationexception-addviewview-layoutpara) out.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the link. I'll study it.